# How do I get rid of <filename>.project.vim files?

Tags: vimrc, sessions, persistent-state, gvim

It seems like any time I edit a file with gvim it creates a litany of files I don't want or seem to need. I understand the `<filename>.~` files are backups of the file before I started editing and `.<filename>.swp` are swap files holding bits of data only while vim is open, but what is the purpose of `<filename>.project.vim`? Can I safely delete them? Can I make gvim stop creating them in the first place?

Comment: I don't believe that is a standard file for vim to create. Can you please try running vim with `-u NONE` (i.e. no `~/.vimrc` to see if it still does it?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier That's  a negative. Also it only does it for files in some directories. I tested in a scratch area and it doesn't do it, but for example a git repo with a bunch of LaTeX stuff in it leaves them behind on every edit.

Comment: So it sounds to me, therefore, like you are loading a plugin which does that instead. Suggest you do a binary search (aka comment half of them) for the plugins you have installed to narrow down the culprit.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier How about `grep -R project.vim ~/.vim`? It looks like [Automatic LaTeX Plugin](http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/) is to blame. I edit so many LaTeX files these days I didn't notice it wasn't happening except on these. That gives me a place to look for how to shut it off. Either I'll answer someday or anybody that looks up how ATP works can answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `doc/automatic-tex-plugin.txt` in the [Automatic LaTeX Plugin](http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/) source:

```
                                                *b:atp_ProjectScript*
                                                *g:atp_ProjectScript*
Setting one of the variables |b:atp_ProjectScript| or
|g:atp_ProjectScript| to 0 the feature will be turned off.  Local
variable, i.e. b: has precedence over the global one g:.  So you can
turned off the feature for only specific files. The global variable
will turn it off for all files.
```

So simply adding:

```
let g:atp_ProjectScript = 0
```

to your `.vimrc` should solve the problem.